# grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 - can it accept standard input?

Tags: security, centos, redhat, grub, grub2

On CentOS 6 we currently encrypt the grub password using the `password --md5` option and we are able to script this into our standard server build.

We are busy migrating to CentOS 7 and it appears that the `password --md5` option has been removed in grub2 and replaced with `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`.

Although I welcome the improved security, I can't find a way to pass a password to the `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` command via standard input, and it appears that grub2 has removed support for md5, the combination of which breaks our script building automation.

Can anyone possibly help with:

1. A way to pass a password to `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` via standard input?; or
2. An alternative pbkdf2 generation utility to `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` that accepts standard input?; or
3. A mechanism for using `--md5` with grub2?

Comment: Why not pregenerate the crypt and automate the editing in of this a la https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/how-to-reset-grub-password-in-linux.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently wrote a tool to do just this -- namely, to be able to more easily generate GRUB2 hashes non-interactively, and to be able to do so on RHEL6. It's on GitHub.

- [burg2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2: Non-interactively generate GRUB2-compatible PBKDF2 hashes from the cmdline with python](https://github.com/ryran/burg2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2)

In the readme you'll also see explanation of how to use the standard `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` to generate hashes non-interactively by piping the password twice with newline.

Comment: Thanks, am marking this as the accepted answer as it looks solid and I appreciate the input, however I got what I needed using "expect -c ..."

Answer (score 8):

`grub-mkpassswd-pbkdf2` takes the [password (twice) from stdin](https://github.com/ryran/burg2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2).

If your password is in `$passwd`:

```
passwd="my test password"
```

You can get the hash with: (Using bash as your shell)

```
echo -e "$passwd\n$passwd" | LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | awk '/hash of / {print $NF}'
```

The AWK prints the last field of the line matching the given pattern, which is the hash. The locale is forced to the default one (`C`), in case the message is translated in other locales.

Comment: You can also use `awk '/grub.pbkdf/{print$NF}'` to not care about different locales.